# probleme to list with readdir

Tags: c, readdir, opendir

I want to list a folder but when I want to print the filename only \n are print

```
void    liste_folder(void)
{
  DIR           *dir;
  struct dirent *test;

  dir = opendir(".");
  while (readdir(dir) != NULL)
    {
      test = malloc(sizeof(*test));
      printf("%s\n", test->d_name);
      free(test);
    }
}

int     main()
{
  liste_folder();
}
```

Comment: You need to assign a value to the `test` variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating memory for `test`, but that doesn't fill it with the directory info. [`readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) allocates the memory for the `dirent` structure for you, so it isn't even necessary. Assign the return-value of `readdir` to `test` instead:

```
while((test = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", test->d_name);
    // the man page says you may not free the dirent
}
```